# Catching shadowed built-in types

Tags: go

In go it is possible to shadow bult-in types like `int`; so is legal this:

```
var a int
a = 1
fmt.Println(a)

int := 2  //<-- catching this
fmt.Println(int)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lU6Z8BW7hzS

Is it possible to catch it with some tools?

Comment: I don't think go vet or any of the go linters detect this. You might try https://arslan.io/2019/06/13/using-go-analysis-to-write-a-custom-linter/ to write your own.

Comment: At the same time, there are only a handful of built-in types, the cognitive load to avoid shadowing them seems pretty inconsequential.

Comment: @Adrian: considering this case I agree with you but, in general projects are based on multiple languages, frameworks, libs, any of them with their cognictive load that amplify itself, so minimizing (eliminating) weird edge cases we have a better programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but the syntax highlighter for the editor I use (Vim) detects predefined types [1], including `int`:

```
syn keyword     goSignedInts        int int8 int16 int32 int64 rune
```

So it doesn't warn you of the situation you describe, but the identifier will be a bold green instead of a normal black, so it's pretty noticeable.

1. https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/1ad72c8e/runtime/syntax/go.vim#L70

Answer (score 0):

There is proposal for that: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38832

Not just shadow is legal, but also struct field:

```
    type myStruct struct {
        int
    }
    a := myStruct{}
    a.int = 2
```

GoLand has IDE check, it will show warning: "Variable 'int' collides with the builtin type", but it show no warning for struct fields.

The problem is: the language allows it, so a few programmers may use this feature on purpose.

Comment: is this case also a form of shadowing?

Comment: Your struct field example is not shadowing, it's an embedded field. It's completely normal and not something that should be alerted by any linter.

Comment: @gigiabbrescia I think not. "shadowing" is appliable to variables. The GoLand also does not use the word "shadow", but "collide". Struct field is just interesting case of colliding with **type** name.

Comment: @Adrian yes I was writing that, thank you

Comment: The struct field isn't "colliding" with anything. It's an embedded field. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types